# Creating resources in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create several resources with a single function.

Right now I have this function:

```
getResource(id) {
let url = this.databaseURL + 'rest/resource/' + id;
return this.http.get(url)
  .map(res => res);
}
```

and then in the class I start the resources:

```
resource1 = [];
resource2 = [];
```

and in the constructor I make the calls:

```
this.getResource('resource1')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.resource1 = data;
          }
        }
      });

this.getResource('resource2')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.resource2 = data;
          }
        }
      });
```

As you can see it is repeating code (and I have to call a lot of resources.) I do not know if you could do something like create the function

```
this.getResources(arrayResources)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.resource1 = data;
      }
    }
  });
```

and in the constructor

```
arrayResources = ['resource1', 'resource2']

this.getResources(arrayResources)
```

But as you have to subscribe to that getResources and also the resources are not defined in the class I'm losing a bit and I do not know how I could do it ... do you think of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this (i make code from head):

```
this.arrayResources = new Array(10);

for(i=0; i<this.arrayResources.length; i++)
{
    this.getResource('resource'+i)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.arrayResources[i] = data;
          }
        }
      });
}
```

I not use separate array for resources names however it is easy to introduce and put into for loop.